# In detail, What is Dynatrace (Application Performance Management) tool

Tags: jakarta-ee, vs-web-application-project, dynatrace

Just heard and verifying about APM Dynatrace tool, i would like to know much more and many details on this. So that i can go ahead and advise my management towards to own this tool.

can any one please let me know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a lot of material on our APM Blog - http://apmblog.compuware.com. dynaTrace is a product that helps developers, testers and operations to ensure their applications work fast and reliable. The core technology of dynaTrace is its PurePath Technology (find a video on YouTube) which allows it to trace every single transaction (= web request, user interaction, batch job, ...) from end-to-end (browser to database). dynaTrace also monitors your infrastructure and with that allows you to figure out whether your application performance problems are related to infrastructure (virtual or physical), app server, web server, app code, database, ...

If you are considering continuous delivery - you may also want to check out the following blog post: http://apmblog.compuware.com/2014/03/13/software-quality-metrics-for-your-continuous-delivery-pipeline-part-i/